# Visual Studio install locations

Tags: c#, visual-studio, location, installation

Can we change the install location for Visual Studio as per our wish? Or Visual Studio will only install under Program Files?

Regards,
Amal

Comment: if my memory serves me right, you should be able to change install location in the setup program.. anyway, what is your Visual Studio version?

Comment: VS2017 Release candidate

Comment: When you go through the installer, you will have the option to select the install location for VS. Why did you need to ask a question here to learn that, rather than just trying it?

Comment: You can have a try with this scenario and if you meet any installation issue, you can share in here or to make it single in another new thread.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio you install comes with tons of smaller components. Many can be installed to another location if you choose to, but still can be some that go only under a fixed location. Why do you want to install it to another location?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Visual Studio into another location when you run the VS installer.

Usually, it is recommended to install it on the system drive (C:) and it will more stable and safe. When you install VS on another drive, most of the VS components still install on the system drive for some reasons, you can have a look at this: [Why Visual Studio 11 Requires Space on the System Drive](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2012/03/07/why-visual-studio-11-requires-space-on-the-system-drive/)